# Aplicación que se ejecuta en thonny pero no en terminal

Tags: python-3.7

Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación python que, si la ejecuto en thonny, funciona sin problema, pero si la ejecuto por terminal da error indicando lo siguiente:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "copy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from binance.client import Client
  File "/home/xxxxxxx/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 5, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 112, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from ._internal_utils import to_native_string
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import is_py2, builtin_str, str
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/compat.py", line 59, in <module>
    from http import cookiejar as cookielib
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/cookiejar.py", line 31, in <module>
    import copy
  File "/home/xxxxx/Desktop/compartido/binance/copytrading/copy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from binance.client import Client
ImportError: cannot import name 'Client' from 'binance.client' (/home/xxxxxx/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/binance/client.py)
```

La verdad es que no tengo ni idea de porqué puede ser, estoy empezando con python y aunque he buscado algo en google, la información que he ido encontrando parece que no tiene mucho que ver con mi problema, ya que casi todo iba relacionado con bugs en el github del proyecto de la clase binance en python.

Alguna ayuda sobre por donde puedo investigar esto? Estoy trabajando con python 3.7.3 y lo tengo configurado como predeterminado, aunque seguramente tampoco tenga mucho que ver esto.

Comment: Parece que ponerle de nombre "copy.py" al archivo de tu aplicación hace que entre en conflicto con una libreria estándar que otra libreria trata de importar. Intenta cambiarle el nombre a otra cosa, por ejemplo a "mycopy.py".

Comment: Lo has clavado @braver, ponlo como respuesta para poder darla por buena por favor. Muchas gracias.